# R : doubles quotes in a paste, how to get rid of the backlashes

Tags: sql, r, sqlite

That seem like an old repeated issue, but none of the posts I found worked in my case. I have this simple SQL query:

```
min.t <- "2017-10-17 00:00:00"
max.t <- "2017-10-17 08:00:00"
query <- paste0('select * from pred where \"current.time\">\"',min.t,'\" and 
\"current.time\"<\"',max.t,'\"')
"select * from pred where \"current.time\">\"2017-10-17 00:00:00\" and 
\"current.time\"<\"2017-10-17 08:00:00\""
```

as you can see the backlashes remain because of the simple quote. I need to keep the simple quotes for the query because the column names contain a dot. If I remove the backlashes from the paste, I get the same result:

```
paste0('select * from pred where "current.time">"',min.t,'" and 
"current.time"<"',max.t,'"')
[1] "select * from pred where \"current.time\">\"2017-10-17 00:00:00\" and 
\"current.time\"<\"2017-10-17 08:00:00\""
```

and

```
 gsub('\\\\', '', query)
```

seem to ignore them.

Comment: Why not use square brackets or backticks (the escaping symbols in SQLite) instead of double quotes (the general identifier symbols in ANSI-SQL)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would phrase your raw SQLite query as this:

```
select *
from pred
where
    "current.time" > '2017-10-17 00:00:00' and
    "current.time" < '2017-10-17 08:00:00';
```

In R, you can just use the exact above query in a character variable, e.g.

```
query <- paste0("select * from pred where \"current.time\" > '2017-10-17 00:00:00' ",
                "and \"current.time\" < '2017-10-17 08:00:00'")
```

Note that we can make a simplification to your `WHERE` clause and use `BETWEEN`, which leads to this:

```
query <- paste0("select * from pred where \"current.time\" between ",
                "'2017-10-17 00:00:01' and '2017-10-17 07:59:59'")
```

Comment: Thanks, but given that my columns have a dot in the name, it looks like I need a double quote for them. Trying with your example gives:
query <- paste0("select * from pred where current.time > '",min.t,"' ",
                "and current.time < '",max.t,"'")
res <- dbGetQuery(tb, query)
Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : 
  no such column: current.time

Comment: @XavierPrudent You're right about needing to escape the column name with a dot.  You really shouldn't be using dots in your column names in the first place.  Can you try running my raw query and see if it works?  Then let me know whether the same query works from R.

Comment: It works :) I am just puzzled understanding why. You replaced the simple quotes by double ones. Do they have the same effect as in bash?

Comment: @XavierPrudent The only change I made was to not put double quotes around the timestamp literals.  As I mentioned in my answer, double quotes can be interpreted to be a column name escaped.